# getting npm install errors angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am getting some errors while installing node modules on another PC, having the same node version (10.15.0).

Where is the error? I have already deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then run `npm install` command, but this didn't help.

```
C:\node\inventory_app_web>npm install
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@7.0.4: Switch to @angular/common/http - see https://angular.io/guide/http
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sohail Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-02T18_09_24_498Z-debug.log
```

Comment: This post should be closed as it is a general issue and may be duplicated, also the reporter responded himself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I had Git installed, but it was only accessible from Git Bash. reinstalled it with second option and it solved my problem:

[image]